# Skipping column names - combining tables from multiple workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to combine a table from multiple workbooks and create a new master workbook which contains all the extracted tables. My current code successfully copies and pastes data from each workbook but still have a few issues and couldn't figure them out by myself.

First, I want to skip the first row, which is just variable names, starting from the second source file. I still need it from the first source file so that my master workbook can have column names in the first row. I tried to achieve this using some loops but it didn't work. Which part do I need to update in order to do this?

Second, is there a way to create an additional column in the master workbook as a flag that shows the source file of data when I copy and paste a table from each individual source file to the master?
For example, if a source excel file is named "file123", the flag column would contain "file123" as its value.

Lastly, in the line of my code where it pastes the copied value,

```
MaWS.Range("A12785").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

I randomly assigned a big number "A12785" but how do I determine this value? Can I just keep it random?

FYI, here is my current code.
My master workbook is named "Master" and has a sheet named "Summary"
My source files have the table in the "data" tab.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Merge()

Dim SrPath As String
Dim MaPath As String
Dim SrName As String
Dim MaName As String
Dim SrTemplate As String
Dim MaTemplate As String
Dim SrWS As Worksheet
Dim MaWS As Worksheet

'Define folders and filenames
SrPath = "C:\Users\Documents\Test\"
MaPath = "C:\Users\Documents\Test\Master\"
SrTemplate = "*.xlsx"  '
MaTemplate = "Master.xlsm"

'Open the template file and get the Worksheet to put the data into
MaName = Dir(MaPath & MaTemplate)
Workbooks.Open SumPath & SumName
Set MaWS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")

'Open each source file, copying the data from each into the template file
SrName = Dir(SrPath & SrTemplate)    'Retrieve the first file
Do While SrName <> ""
    'Open the source file and get the worksheet with the data we want.
    Workbooks.Open SrPath & SrName
    Set SrWS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("data")
    'Copy the data from the source and paste at the end of Summary sheet
    SrWS.Range("A1:N35").Copy
    sumWS.Range("A12785").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    'Close the current sourcefile and get the next
    Workbooks(SrName).Close SaveChanges:=False        'close
    MyName = Dir                    'Get next file
Loop
'Now all sourcefiles are copied into the Template file. Close and save it
Workbooks(MaName).Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you write a macro for several hours if you can get the result in 15 minutes? Watch the [**video**](https://www.google.com/search?q=power+query+excel+2016+from+multiple+workbooks&sxsrf=ALeKk0279-psX5BpVJDrtv9TfRiRDwy_Ag:1602230284369&source=lnms&tbm=vid&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj1ncr3hKfsAhUVBhAIHSrIAOkQ_AUoAXoECBcQAw&biw=1280&bih=881) for 8 minutes and repeat the steps for 7 minutes. As a result, you will also get a script, not a VBA but an M-language

Comment: Tell me, is there any data in the Master.xlsm template on the Summary sheet? Or are you starting from scratch? I see that you (yet?) Do not check if the data from the next book is already on the sheet before copying it

Comment: The summary tab in the master workbook doesn't contain any data.

Comment: Well! In this case no need each time get last row with `.End(xlUp)` - just set long variable `NextRow` (or `LastRow` or any other) to 1 (first row in sheet), paste next portion (34 rows of data from Range("A2:N35")) and increase `NextRow=NextRow+34`. When start do `If NextRow = 1 then <copy headers from Range("A1:N1")>`

Comment: But try the **Get & Transform Data** from the Data Tab tool anyway - it's amazingly easy! Any video that collects data from multiple books takes 8-12 minutes, and the data collection operation itself is even faster.